# JavaScript / JSON Recursive Logic Issue using hasOwnProperty

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Here is the JSON, the specific problem has the comment `// doesn't get parsed currently`

```
var oarsObject = [{
    "coordinateReferenceSystem": "26782,15851 <-- not in a value",
        "positionReferenceType": "geogWgs84",
        "geogWgs84": {
        "latitude": {
            "value": 0.50018514607964015
        },
            "longitude": {
            "value": -1.587237735514361
        },
            "height": {
            "value": 0.0
        }
    }
}, {
    "coordinateReferenceSystem": {
        "value": "26782,15851 <-- was in a value"
    },
        "positionReferenceType": {
        "value": "geogWgs84"
    },
        "geogWgs84": {
        "latitude": {
            "value": 0.5001841257180204
        },
            "longitude": {
            "value": -1.5869069927615211
        },
            "height": {
            "value": 0.0
        }
    }
}, {
    "coordinateReferenceSystem": "26782,15851",
        "positionReferenceType": "geogWgs84",
        "geogWgs84": {
        "latitude": {
            "value": 0.49997645018241949
        },
            "longitude": {
            "value": -1.5869078356348387
        },
            "height": {
            "value": 0.0
        }
    }
}, {
    "coordinateReferenceSystem": "26782,15851",
        "positionReferenceType": "geogWgs84",
        "geogWgs84": {
        "latitude": {
            "value": 0.4999774704207946
        },
            "longitude": {
            "value": -1.5872385394554729
        },
            "height": {
            "value": 0.0
        }
    },
        "nest": {
        "level_1": {
            "child_1": {
                "value": "child_1 <-- level 1",
                "gchild_1": {"value": "gchild_1 <-- level 2"} // doesn't get parsed currently
            },
                "child_2": {
                "gchild_1": {
                    "value": "gchild_1 <-- level 2"
                }
            },
                "child_3": {
                "gchild_2": {
                    "ggchild_1": {
                        "value": "ggchild_1 <-- level 3"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}];
```

I thought that the recursion was working very well, but then the edge case above came up where additional properties were given in the object where a "value" property existed. I have a couple of choices, I can have the JSON spit out differently OR I can try to account for these edge cases, which seems more scalable to me. Here is how I am iterating and recursing now -

```
function propertyTest(currentObject) {
    for (var property in currentObject) {
        if (currentObject[property].hasOwnProperty('value')) {
            // if the "value" shoe fits
            $('#method1').append(property + ', ' + currentObject[property].value + '<br />');
        } else if (typeof currentObject[property] === "object") {
            // recurses when needed
            propertyTest(currentObject[property]);
        } else {
            // spits out "valueless" info
            $('#method1').append(property + ' ' + currentObject[property] + '<br />');
        }
    }
}
```

Appending to the div is just a way to output the test conveniently.The code is probably not as neat as it should be right now, but I'll clean it up after testing.

The question - how do I recurse / iterate properly so that I can retrieve these edge case values? Any suggestions or help would be grandly appreciated!

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/eQEt3/8/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like

```
function propertyTest(currentObject) {
    for (var property in currentObject) {
        if (currentObject[property].hasOwnProperty('value')) {
            $('#method1').append(property + ', ' + currentObject[property].value + '<br />');
        } 
        if (typeof currentObject[property] === "object") {
            propertyTest(currentObject[property]);
        } else if(property != 'value') {
            $('#method1').append(property + ' ' + currentObject[property] + '<br />');
        }
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eQEt3/9/)

Which I would simplify to:

```
function propertyTest(currentObject, key) {
    for (var property in currentObject) {
        if (typeof currentObject[property] === "object") {
            propertyTest(currentObject[property], property);
        } else {
            $('#method1').append(
                (property=='value' && key ? key+',' : property)
                + ' ' + currentObject[property] + '<br />'
            );
        }
    }
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/eQEt3/12/)

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense.